# Can we create new EC2, RDS services under free tier when there are already existing other EC2, RDS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

On AWS, I already have an EC2 instance and PostgreSQL RDS which is working fine for more than 2 years. Now I added new EC2 instance and a new PostgreSQL RDS ( both are under free tier ). Later I found that the billing is added to this RDS even though I have selected free tier. Is this possible to create another EC2 and another RDS in the Free Tier when there is a EC2 and RDS running more than 2 years?

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount provided by AWS. Some discounts are provided only for the **first 12 months** of an AWS Account, while some apply *every* month.

For **Amazon EC2 instances, the AWS Free Tier provides the following discounts **for the first 12 months**:**

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
- 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region

For **Amazon RDS databases**, the AWS Free Tier provides the following discounts **for the first 12 months**:

- 750 Hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro, db.t3.micro, and db.t4g.micro Instances usage running MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL databases each month (applicable DB engines)
- 20 GB of General Purpose (SSD) database storage
- 20 GB of storage for database backups and DB Snapshots

Both discounts are only provided for the **first 12 months** of your AWS Account. You might have selected services that are **"free tier eligible"** but they would not be free because your AWS Account is older than 12 months.